# Sklearn Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I started on my journey on machine learning a few months back, Today I was practicing my skills and I tried I few different Algorithms, I used Linear Regression, Decision Tree Classifier and Support Vector Machine, My code is very simple and it's working just fine (" I guess " ), But since I'm new pardon me if this a silly question, But using the Linear Regression and Decision Tree Classifier give me an accuracy from 1.04 to 1.22, But if I use SVM it give me 0.72, So I'm confuse since I read that SVM is better than Linear Regression in speed and performance, So can you guys please help me clarify this. :)
Thanks in Advance :)

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


dataset = pd.read_csv("/home/jairo/Downloads/diabetes.csv")
dataset.shape

x = dataset.drop(['Outcome'], axis=1)
y = dataset['Outcome']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()


classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
predic = classifier.predict(x_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predic.round(), normalize=False)
print("Accuracy : {}".format(score/100))
```

THIS IS THE LAST OUTPUT THAT I GOT:

Accuracy : 1.15

Answer (score 0):

Classification performance is **highly dependent** on your type of input and what you want to classify. One isn't objectively "better" than the other. To perhaps add some insight into your results, SVM works by trying to find a hyperplane that divides your data into classes. If you had positive and negative as your two potential outcomes, for example, it would try to find the hyperplane that divides your points in n-dimensional space such that all points on either side of the hyperplane belong to that class. n here refers to the number of features.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explaining this to me, So Basically SVM works kind of like k-nearest neighbors, right? which it divide your data into classes and compare to which classes the points belong to, Right? correct me if I'm wrong please. :)

Comment: Not exactly - I would recommend looking at the [SVM documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) and the documentation of other modules in the scikit learn library to get further information, but all of these models use different algorithms to try to classify data, and as such have specific advantages and disadvantages. Without more information about your input and what you want to classify, it's hard to explain further, but the scikit-learn website is a great resource for you to find what works for your particular situation